# Occasional loss of session variables

Tags: php, apache, session, session-cookies, session-variables

We have an application (PHP) that requests user data on page 1 via php form -> mariadb DB: https://www.example.com/folder1/index.php
After error checking, it passes user to https://www.example.com/folder1/index_success.php, saves session variables, and then passes user to https://www.example.com/folder2/index.php using absolute path.
On folder 2, the session variables are checked and if they are missing it will pass the user back to folder1/index.php to complete the form. This makes sure that we don't have any user on folder2 that has not completed form submission and trying to access directly.

Occasionally we see that session variables are missing when user lands on folder2. The form data is on the database, but the variables have not been set.

It is not browser specific and it is only 2-3% of the time. I have tested on my own Chrome browser and most of the time it's fine, but occasionally it happens. If I complete the form again, it then works fine.

If there are any ideas as to what might cause random occasional loss of session data that would be very helpful.

The session folder is set correctly in php.ini

Apache with PHP Version 5.6.40 using PHP-FPM

Comment: sessions do expire. Do your logs show the time of each request? Maybe there's too large a gap between the requests to each page.

Comment: But...if you're saving data into the DB, why do you need session data? Surely redirect the user to `folder2/index.php?id=123` where 123 is the ID of the record in the DB they just entered in the form. That way a) it won't matter if the session expires in between requests, b) people can view old records as well as just the current one. You can have security checks if needed to ensure no-one views a record they shouldn't. I don't know the purpose of this app or whether this suggestion is logical, but certainly it's a much more conventional way to deal with submits and redirects in a web app.